# How to execute a function every n seconds?

Tags: php, performance, cron, sleep

I'm writing a monitor in PHP that's monitoring the uptime of a host. 
So every n seconds I like to ask the host for it's status. I could simply make a cronjob that executes every minute, but I could also do something like this:

```
while(1)
{
  check_status();
  sleep(60);
}
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better method is to use cron.

CRON will launch your PHP every minute. If your PHP crash, it will be relaunched. If you launch manually the PHP, and it crashes, you'll have to manually relaunch it. More than this, with CRON, you'll not have to care about what's happening on the machine boot time.

Final note : PHP is not really the best tool to make this sort of things ;)

Cheers,

K.

Comment: But what about performance? Or doesn't it make significant difference? I know PHP is not the best tool for it, it's meant to be a POC ;)

Comment: Letting a single process (your PHP) running permanently will cost more than launching it regularly. You'll have a small overhead at IO Level (loading of the file, launching the PHP interpreter ...) but probably will be very, very small ;). BUT (important) : do not forget to manage the case where your PHP will be launched two times. It will happen if one execution last for more than 60 seconds, crontab will launch it before the first one has the time to end.

Answer (score 1):

Do the cron job, if the machine re-starts your process will automatically restart.

Comment: You can also make an upstart job for it. But does it make difference in performance?

Comment: No idea, I have never used Upstart, but I would guess any performance hit is more likely to come from your code that you are running every 60 seconds compared to the cpu cost of the scheduling.